# How to configure Prettier in VS Code to ignore comments for SQL code?

Tags: sql, prettier, prettier-vscode

So the issue is illustrated as follows:
Before using Prettier to format:

```
SELECT *
FROM
table a --SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE 1-1
```

And after using Prettier:

```
SELECT  *
FROM TABLE a --
SELECT  *
FROM TABLE
WHERE 1-1
```

How can I disable formatting for inline comments ( or any sort of comment in general)